# Adding columns across items in Pandas panels in one shot?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, panel

I have the following Panel  called `stocks`:

```
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 1681 (major_axis) x 5 (minor_axis)
Items axis: AAPL to OPK
Major_axis axis: 2010-01-04 00:00:00 to 2016-09-07 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: Open to Volume
```

The Items axis consist of the names of the stocks, and the Minor_axis consists of many attribute columns for the particular stock, such as 'Open', 'Close, 'Volume' etc.

I'm trying to add a new column (attribute)called ['Log_Return']  to all items(stocks) at the same time.

I've tried the following and variations of it but there seems to be no changes being made to my panel

```
stocks[:]['Log_Return'] = np.log( stocks.loc[:,:, 'Close'] / stocks.loc[:,:, 'Close'].shift(1)) 
#This created an additional item instead of a column in minor_axis

stocks['AAPL':'OPK']['Log_Return'] = np.log( stocks.loc[:,:, 'Close'] / stocks.loc[:,:, 'Close'].shift(1))

 #This didn't do anything; no errors but no changes being made to my panels as well


# AAPL and OPK are the only stocks in the items axis and are equivalent to the ':', in the right 
hand side of the equation.
```

I tried using iteration as well

```
for i in stocks:
    stocks.i['Log_Return']= np.log( stocks.loc[i,:, 'Close'] /stocks.loc[i,: ,'Close'])
```

And got this error     `'Panel' object has no attribute 'i'`

```
stocks.AAPL
              Open    High     Low   Close       Volume  
Date                                                          
2010-01-04   30.49   30.64   30.34   30.57  123432050.0      
2010-01-05   30.66   30.80   30.46   30.63  150476004.0      
2010-01-06   30.63   30.75   30.11   30.14  138039594.0      
2010-01-07   30.25   30.29   29.86   30.08  119282324.0      
2010-01-08   30.04   30.29   29.87   30.28  111969081.0      
2010-01-11   30.40   30.43   29.78   30.02  115557365.0      


stocks.OPK
             Open   High    Low  Close     Volume
Date                                             
2010-01-04   1.80   1.97   1.76   1.95   234455.0
2010-01-05   1.64   1.95   1.64   1.93   135712.0
2010-01-06   1.90   1.92   1.77   1.79   546586.0
2010-01-07   1.79   1.94   1.76   1.92   138622.0
2010-01-08   1.92   1.94   1.86   1.89    62425.0
2010-01-11   1.90   1.95   1.89   1.91   130195.0
```

I feel like I'm making a simple mistake but I can't get my head thinking straight today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to iterate over `items` of panel object. In your case iterate over `stocks.items` instead of `stocks`. Here is a general example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
p = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(2, 5, 2), items=['Item1', 'Item2'],major_axis=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=5), minor_axis=['A', 'B'])
for i in p.items:
    p[i]['C'] =  p[i]['A']+p[i]['B']
print p['Item1']
print p['Item2']

# reindex to new minor axis
p = p.reindex_axis(['A', 'B', 'C'], 'minor_axis')
print p.minor_axis

results in 

                   A         B         C
2000-01-01 -0.442373  0.842567  0.400194
2000-01-02  0.668583  1.809871  2.478454
2000-01-03  0.979304  1.022991  2.002295
2000-01-04  0.910955  0.282959  1.193914
2000-01-05  1.265542 -1.626789 -0.361247
                   A         B         C
2000-01-01 -0.635350 -0.138817 -0.774166
2000-01-02 -0.573246  0.731871  0.158625
2000-01-03 -0.027341  1.033315  1.005974
2000-01-04 -1.152284  0.210650 -0.941634
2000-01-05 -0.504819  0.682751  0.177933

Index([u'A', u'B', u'C'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works! I knew it was something simple I was missing.   =)

Comment: What's strange is that when I  print stocks.APPL,  I see the column has been added, but when I check via  `stocks.minor_axis`, It's not listed;

`Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], dtype='object')`

Comment: the panel needs to be reindexed. See the new edit. hope that helps.